# Is there a specific name for these sentence parts?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is there any specific name for the bold portions of the following sentences, or for their structure?

> **It has been suggested** that drinking water is good for your health.
>
> **It is unknown** how long could this last.

Comment: Your two examples are in the form of *extraposition* constructions. In conversation you could probably refer to the bolded expressions as either the matrix clause or as the nucleus (of the matrix clause) and the other person would probably understand what you are talking about, imo. The unbolded expressions, which are subordinate clauses, can be referred to as the *extraposed subject*. Note that the *extraposed subject* is not the grammatical subject. In both of your examples, the grammatical subject is the dummy pronoun *"it"*.

Comment: @F.E. Why not write that as an answer? Seems reasonable to me, and there are other questions mentioning extraposition on EL&U, although we don't have a tag just for that.

Comment: @FeralOink Well, I'm procrastinating before getting my coffee and hadn't intended to write a "real" answer type of post. :)

Comment: @F.E. Okay, I understand how that can be!

Answer (score 2):

*It has been suggested* is a passive construction.

*It is unknown* is a clause having dummy *it* as its subject. The verb is copular *is*, and the complement is the predicative adjective *unknown*.

Comment: And the unbolded terms are a clause and a phrase that are the logical subjects of both sentences for which the dummy, *it* stands in.